# The following Post Correspondence Problem unsolvable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I have been trying to play around with the following Post Correspondence Problem for about one hour now with no success, which leads me to believing the following problem is unsolvable.

Is the following Post Correspondence Problem solvable? I would appreciate any suggestions. I ended up with a huge long string of domino's, with a reoccurring pattern.

[01/0101], [1/0], [010/1], [00/0]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: [Post Correspondence Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem)

Answer (score 2):

Answer is

00 00 1  01

0 0  0 0101

Comment: It would help the answer and the OP if you could provide more details as to how you arrived at it.

Comment: +1, Thanks for the reply. Can you please explain how you got this?

Comment: Essentially brute force and/or dumb luck. By considering trains of length 1, then 2, then 3, none of which works. Of course not all combinations need to  be checked (you do not start or end with second or third car). You also have restrictions on the length of trains being the same (so $2x=2z+t$ where $x,y,z,t$ are the numbers of cars #1,2,3,4 used in the train). So it is not that you check all $4^4$ cases.